# Inconsistencies in flag terminology

Tags: bug, flags

Recently, the terminology for flagging a post has changed from "it's offensive, abusive or hate speech" to "inappropriate".

However, the flagging history in the profile page still shows "N posts marked offensive".

I think this page's terminology should also be updated to say "N posts marked as inappropriate". Alternatively, we can preserve the history and have "N posts marked offensive" for flags raised before the change and "M posts marked inappropriate" for flags raised after the change, but I doubt this is worth the hassle and/or visual overload.

Comment: Personally I'd like to see "inappropriate" on the flag dialog go. It's causing confusion with people using to to flag stuff that's merely off topic.

Comment: Same inconsistency: deleted answers still say "spam or offensive", not "spam or inappropriate". Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GqeZk.png